# React-native - why is setState hook not executing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working on a React Native app. I have created a listener, which executes a function upon connecting to a websocket:

```
const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState<string>(someValue);

ws.on('connect', () => {            
    ...
    setTimeout(() => { void updateSongsState() }, 1000); // Mentioned function
});

const updateSongsState = async (): Promise<void> => {
    ...
    setLoadingState(someNewValue);
}

...

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loadingState);
}, [loadingState]);
```

This function is supposed to update the state to a new value, but it only happens the first time. When i open this component again, I can see it is rerendering, and the updateSongsState function is being executed, but loadingState does not change.

I have set up a useEffect() function to capture state changes and console.log() the state, but it doesn't execute, meaning the loadingState didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what caused this issue, and I've managed to fix this. Callback function for the websocket connection event updated the state only **on first render of this component**. This made me think that this callback might be updating the state from the first render only, because this event handler was assigned only once at the beginning. What could have happenned there was that every next render, the callback was trying to update a non-existing state from the first render, and thats why I couldn't see the result on any next render. I decided to **assign this event handler on each render, so that this callback will always refer to the state from current render**, and the problem has been resolved.